# Bash script with docker command not running when passing argument | Env: WSL2 with docker desktop

Tags: windows, bash, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to WSL + docker desktop on windows. normally this would not be an issue. but i have no clue what im doing wrong here. I have a script /usr/local/bin/mysqlcmd which takes a SQL query as arg and supposed to print it out after executing a `docker exec` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

args="$1"
echo "Recieved $args"

sql_query="'mysql -u root -proot --database dev --batch -e \"$args\"'"
echo "SQL query: $sql_query"

docker exec -it hellomaven_db_1 bash -c 'mysql -u root -proot --database dev --batch -e "select * from location limit 10"'
echo "FAILURE"
docker exec -it hellomaven_db_1 bash -c "$sql_query"
```

and the output when i run `mysqlcmd 'select * from location limit 4'` is

```
Recieved select * from location limit 10
SQL query: 'mysql -u root -proot --database dev --batch -e "select * from location limit 4"'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
id      lat     lon     datetime_ts     datetime_id
1       -0.1997 -34.7696        2020-11-06 11:32:37     1604662359
2       -0.682  -34.4279        2020-11-06 11:32:47     1604662369
3       -1.1641 -34.0864        2020-11-06 11:32:57     1604662378
4       -1.6714 -33.7267        2020-11-06 11:33:06     1604662388

FAILURE
bash: mysql -u root -proot --database dev --batch -e "select * from location limit 10": command not found
failed to resize tty, using default size
                                        %
```

what bugs me is the **`bash: mysql -u root -proot --database dev --batch -e "select * from location limit 10": command not found`**. both the docker exec commands are identical. or i am missing something ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to connect directly to the database's published ports using the `mysql` client tool on your host, or a MySQL client library in a more robust language; you do not need `docker exec` here.

Comment: yes, it does work this way, ```docker  exec -it hellomaven_db_1 mysql -u root -proot --database dev -e "select * from location limit 4"```. However if i use the same command in a script (passing the sql command as arg), it doesnt. exits with ```OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"mysql -u root -proot --database dev --batch -e \\\"select * from location limit 10\\\"\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the pair of single quotes, try :

```
sql_query="mysql -u root -proot --database dev --batch -e \"$args\""
```